# Variable Error Bars in Google Sheets Graphs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, statistics

I have a data series that consists of multiple data series. I want to graph the average and the variance. I already calculated a single data series for the average and for the variance.

Now I want to display the data series with variance and I would like to use the error bars feature to display the variance. The problem is that you can only enter a single value for the whole data series. Is there a way to solve this with Google sheets or do I have to resort to Excel, where this is possible? I would like to do it with sheets, so I can collaborate on this with my colleagues.

This is my current graph, as you can see only one constant variance value is possible:

[image: The current graph with only one variance value graphed]

Comment: Would be nice as a new feature :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really a better answer but more expressing your idea in a different way. Plot Average-variance under, variance under, variance over:

[image: WA101633 example]

The above is a stacked area chart with the first series transparent.

Comment: Accepted the answer because of the nice graph visualizing what I meant. Currently this seems to be the only way to get variance plotted.

Answer (score 2):

One solution that came into my mind would be to create two additional data series: Average - variance, Average + variance and graph these.

This would not display as error bars, but the variance would be clearly visible.

I will try this workaround but I am still waiting for a better answer.